# jQuery selecting an element with any visible 2nd level children

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code in which I'm trying to hide and show `div.validation-summary-errors` based on whether or not it has any errors inside

```
$('div.validation-summary-errors').each(function (index, element) {
    if ( ????? ) {
        $(element).parent().css({ "visibility": "visible" });
    }
    else {
        $(element).parent().css({ "visibility": "hidden" });
    }
});
```

The mark up looks like the following. This is the case where is should be hidden since the inner `li` does not have any error inside and `display: none`

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors">
   <ul>
      <li style="display:none"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what does an error look like? Can't help you look for unknown elements. Also `display:none` won't be reversed using `visibility`..  simple `hide()` or `show()` will work

Comment: <li>Error Message</li> Could be any error though. THanks

Comment: Do you realize that you can just show them all?  The empty ones will occupy no space in the page and will not be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($(this).find('li').text().length){
    //there's an error
}else{
    //there is no error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. You'll want to iterate the list items and not the `ul` itself like you are in your example.

```
$('div.validation-summary-errors li').each(function (index, element) {
    var $el = $(element);
    if ($el.text().length > 0) {
        $el.parent().css({ "visibility": "visible" });
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried your answer it may be perfectly valid but so it Ohgodwhy's... what to do. perhaps a tie-breaker: reason why one performs better than other? If not I'll just accept either lol

Comment: You'll want to cache the jQuery'd element if you will use it more than once within the each function body.

Comment: $('div.validation-summary-errors li').each(function (index, element) {
        var $el = $(element);
        if ($el.text().length > 0) {
            $el.parent().css({ "visibility": "visible" });
        }
        else {
            $el.parent().css({ "visibility": "hidden" });
        }
    });​

I don't know why but the following gave me a 'syntax error' so this no work better than ohmygods. Thank you though

Answer (score 1):

```
var errorEls=$('.validation-summary-errors');

errorEls.filter(':has(li:empty').show().end().filter(':not(:has(li:empty))').hide()
```

If you have inline css with `display:none` as shown...`css visibility` will not make it visible.

`show()` and `hide()` will change `display`

Comment: That's ok I'm not making the li visible but its parent().parent() Ohmygod's answer worked fine. THanks

Comment: dumb question but when errors are changed why not change the css then? You have already targeted the elements with jQuery when errors get modified